# Foundation() is undefined when CListView is in the page

Tags: php, jquery, yii, zurb-foundation, clistview

I have a Yii Layout, called `Main`, it loads all the CSS and the JavaScript, correctly ordered.

So, i have two views, one just have pure HTML, and the other one have something like this :

```
    <?php
        $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('agenda');
        $dataProvider->pagination->pageSize=5;

        $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            'enablePagination'=>true,
            'itemView'=>'_agenda',   // refers to the partial view named '_agenda'
            'pager' => array(
                'class' => 'CLinkPager',
                'header' => false,
                'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'pager'),
                'maxButtonCount' => '10',
                'cssFile'=>'css/my.css',

            ),
        ));
    ?>
```

**My problem :**

The second one throw this exception `Undefined is not a function` and aim to the line with `$(document).foundation();` in the code.

Is the only error it throws, and both have the same JavaScripts and CSS imported.

They are incompatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, i just had conflicts with the Foundation's jQuery and Yii's jQuery.

The solution is just use this at top :

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery'); ?>
```

Remove others jQuery and  move the `foundation.min.js` to the bottom.